# Caused InvalidUseOfMatchersException for clearly mocked class

Tags: mockito

I got error while running JUnit test with Mockito's matcher

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Here is source code.

```
class A
{
    public String getField()
    {
        return "hi";
    }
}

@Test
public void testA()
{
    final A a = mock(A.class);
    when(a.getField()).thenReturn(Matchers.any(String.class));
    a.getField();
}
```

What is problem here? Please open my eyes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an [**argument** matcher](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/be6d53f62790ac7c9cf07c32485343ce94e1b563/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers): `Matchers.any(String.class)`. An argument  matcher is not intended to be used as a return a value of a stubbed method.

An argument matcher should be used when you need to customize the way a method is stubbed :

```
when(a.sayHello(Matchers.any(String.class))).thenReturn("Hello");
```

In your example, you must return an instance of String and not a matcher :

```
when(a.getField()).thenReturn("theFieldValue");
```

Comment: Many thanks! That is really surprise for me! Is there any chance to use similar approach for returning value? Are there "mocking return value" or "returning real value" the only possibilities here?

Comment: Yes... i guess but to be sure i need to understand what you are trying to do. May you could ask another question with more details on your real problem.

Comment: This answer is correct, of course, but it's not really applicable to the class that OP is trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the classic error of mocking the class that you're trying to test.  The whole point of mocking is that you remove *other* classes from consideration by your test.  So if you're testing a class `A` that uses an object of class `B` in some way, you might make a mock of class `B`.  But you wouldn't mock the class that you're actually testing, because then you are no longer testing the class, but testing the mocking framework.

In order to test the method you've supplied, it doesn't make sense to use Mockito at all; because there's no additional class that you want to remove from consideration by your test.  The only class is `A` - the one you're testing.

Your test should just be the following

```
public class TestA {

    private A toTest = new A();

    @Test
    public void getFieldReturnsHi() {
        assertEquals("Hi", toTest.getField());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. The point of code example was just to show simple use case for Exception throwing that I have on real testing app. The problem was as @gontard mentioned. So thanks any way.